# Setting S3 Bucket permissions when writing between 2 AWS Accounts while running from Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I have a scala jar which I am calling from AWS Glue job. My jar writes to write a DataFrame to an S3 bucket in another AWS account which has KMS Encryption turned on. I am able to write to the bucket but I am not able to add the destination bucket owner permission to access the files. I can achieve this if simply use Glue Writer but with straight Spark, it just not work. I have read all the documentation and I am setting following bucket policies in hadoop configuration.

def writeDataFrameInTargetLocation( sparkContext:SparkContext = null, dataFrame: DataFrame, location: String,
fileFormat: String,saveMode:String,encryptionKey:Option[String] = Option.empty,kms_region:Option[String]=Option("us-west-2")): Unit = {

if(encryptionKey.isDefined) {
val region = if(kms_region.isDefined) kms_region.getOrElse("us-west-2")
else
"us-west-2"

```
    sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.enableServerSideEncryption", "false")
    sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.cse.enabled", "true")
    sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.cse.encryptionMaterialsProvider", "com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.cse.KMSEncryptionMaterialsProvider")
    sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.cse.kms.keyId", encryptionKey.get) // KMS key to encrypt the data with
      sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.cse.kms.region", region) // the region for the KMS key
    sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.canned.acl", "BucketOwnerFullControl")
    sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.acl.default", "BucketOwnerFullControl")
    sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.acl", "bucket-owner-full-control")
    sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.acl", "BucketOwnerFullControl")
  }
  else {
    sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.canned.acl", "BucketOwnerFullControl")
    sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.acl.default", "BucketOwnerFullControl")
    sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.acl", "bucket-owner-full-control")
    sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.acl", "BucketOwnerFullControl")
  }

    val writeDF = dataFrame
      .repartition(5)
      .write

    
      writeDF
        .mode(saveMode)
        .option(Header, true)
        .format(fileFormat)
        .save(location)
    }
```

Comment: what's the error that you are encountering?

Comment: add the data source not just add the s3 info on the code.

Comment: Not getting any error but the owner of the account where  I am writing the data cannot access. It says Access Denied. I read in documentation to add these but it does not seem to work. sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.canned.acl", "BucketOwnerFullControl")
    sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.acl.default", "BucketOwnerFullControl")
    sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.acl", "bucket-owner-full-control")
    sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.acl", "BucketOwnerFullControl")

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using the S3AFileSystem implementation for the "`s3`" scheme (i.e. URLs of the form "`s3://...`"). You can check that by looking at `sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.get("fs.s3.impl")`. If that is the case, then you actually need to set the hadoop properties for "`fs.s3a.*`" not "`fs.s3.*`".

Then the correct settings would be:

```scala
sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.canned.acl", "BucketOwnerFullControl")
sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.acl.default", "BucketOwnerFullControl")
```

The `S3AFileSystem` implementation is not using any of the properties under "`fs.s3`". You can see that by investigating the code related to the following hadoop source code link:
https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/43e8ac60971323054753bb0b21e52581f7996ece/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3a/Constants.java#L268